# How to show/hide content on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle, slidetoggle

I am trying to find a solution to open one `div` by clicking a link, and close/toggle all other open `div`s at the same time.

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/6Ptkw/1/

I thought this was the right way, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you were close, but note that jsfiddle by default wraps everything in an onDomReady function closure, meaning that your slideonlyone function is no longer visible.

http://jsfiddle.net/6Ptkw/5/

the jsFiddle you posted would have code like this

```
$(function(){
    function slideonlyone(){
        //your code   
    };

});
```

one that `onDomReady` function exits, you would no longer have any scope at which to reference the `slideonlyone` function

I changed it to nowrapper, so that it would be available at the global scope.  This is generally bad practice, and you should attach the click events via

```
$("a").click(function(){

})
```

rather than doing `<a href="javascript:">`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code (just adopt it to your elements)
this "slides open" a div element:

```
$('#workload').click(function(){
        $('#work').load('pagehere.jsp');
        $('#work').animate({
        height: '25%',
        fontSize: "3em",
        borderWidth: "10px"
    }, 1000 );   });
```

The just hide other elements with with the .hide() function. :) hope this helps a bit!